# How to alter the URL path alias generated by content type programmatically?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

Our current url pattern is [node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:title]. What we need is a way to not to include the parent menu link items and only include the child menu link items.

For example:

[image: Current Menu Structure]

The expected output is the following:

- When Any menu link is placed at the same level as "Fourth level 1" (under Top level), it should be ".com/Second-level1/Third-level-1/Fourth-level-3"
- Current issue is that the URL is generated as ".com/Top-Level/Second-level1/Third-level-1/Fourth-level-3"
- We want to remove Top level, Top level 2, top level 3, etc removed from URL path alias.
- Depending upon the placement of the menu link item, it should always contain the menu links 1 level above (if applicable)
- The expected url pattern for third level 2 (under Top level/Second level 1) is ".com/second-level-1/third-level-2"

---

Updated:

I ended up write a custom module to call the hook_alter using the pathauto that just removes the first part of the URL before the node save event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this module https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto with this you define the custom path use token

Comment: I am Path Auto already with the following pattern: [node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:title]. The issue is that i do not want i do not want the links such as "Top Level", "Top Level 1", to show up in the URL path. I need assistance in removing the "top level" before the URL is generated.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to get this to work using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, together with the [Path Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathrules) module, using an approach like so:

- Rules Event: around the time a node is saved (or updated, etc).
- Rules Condition: use [Path Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathrules) which provides various Rules Conditions "*for checking the URL against a given string*" (check this module's project page for examples of such checking). It seems that checking your URL patterns should be straight forward with this module.
- Rules Action: use the "Create or delete a node's URL alias" action to change the URL alias. This Rules Action is similar to using the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, you can use tokens to create an appropriate path.

Comment: I tried that, but i noticed that when i select create or delete a node's URl alias, i am asked to enter the language, which will not work. I need the ability when the node is saved and before it is entered into the db, i need to take the given url path alias and alter it by removing any menu link item i don't want.